# Open file in existing electron window instead of creating new one in Windows

Tags: electron

On macOs, there's an app event `open-file` that's triggered when opening a file association with your app. Which allows you to open your file in an existing app window.

On windows when opening a new file it just creates a new app window instead of opening it in the existing one.

How do I get behaviour like in macOs on windows?

my code:

```js
app.on('will-finish-launching', () => {
  app.on('open-file', async (event, path) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    if (!win) {
      win = await createWindow()
    }

    let openFilePath
    if (process.platform === 'win32' && process.argv.length >= 2) {
      openFilePath = process.argv[1]
    }

    if (process.platform === 'darwin') {
      openFilePath = path
    }

    win.webContents.send('open-file', openFilePath)
  })
})

app.on('ready', async () => {
  if (!app.isPackaged && !process.env.IS_TEST) {
    // Install Vue Devtools
    try {
      await installExtension(VUEJS_DEVTOOLS)
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Vue Devtools failed to install:', e.toString())
    }
  }
  if (!win) {
    win = await createWindow()
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The docs mention that you need to call `event.preventDefault()` in order to handle it. It also fires before the `ready` event. Have you tried something like this?

```js
app.on("open-file", (event, path) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    // create the main window here
    // this is usually done on app.on("ready")
    // but this event fires before "ready"
  }
  // if you already had a mainWindow or just finished
  // creating it for the first time then handle the file
  let file = null;
  let openFilePath = null;
  if (process.platform == "win32" && process.argv.length >= 2) {
    openFilePath = process.argv[1];
  }
  if (process.platform == "darwin") {
    openFilePath = path;
  }
  file = fs.readFileSync(openFilePath, "utf-8");
  // now do stuff with the file such as sending it to the renderer
  mainWindow.webContents.send("file-opened", file);
});
```

Comment: I've updated my original question with this code, but the app still opens in a new window.
[Documentation](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/main/docs/api/app.md#event-open-file-macos) states that the `open-file` event is for macOs